# How to prevent the redraw of a managed winform on programmatic resize?

Tags: winforms, flicker, redraw

I have a .net 4.0 winforms project where I need to programmatically set the bounds (aka size) of a window (System.Windows.Forms.Form) and add/remove controls to/from it, at the same time, without visible flicker. The form is not user-resizable, the only place where its size is changed is the this.Bounds = foo / this.DesktopBounds = foo / ... call.

I already read about preventing flicker by sending WM_SETREDRAW using p/invoke, and about SuspendRedraw/SuspendLayout and friends. I still see flicker happening, and nailed the prob down to:

Windows redraws the form on setting its bounds/size, even if redraw was disabled.

I guess this is caused not by the form itself, but by the window manager somehow?

So - is there a way to absolutely prevent redrawing anything, in any circumstances, and then re-enabling redraw and refresh manually afterwards? Kind of "freeze window and display a snapshot", change stuff, and "replace snapshot with updated window (incl. position and size) in 1 go" ?

Thanks, cheers,
  Tim

Answer (score 0):

Use the ResizeRedraw property of the form. Set it to false.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.resizeredraw.aspx

You'll also need to redraw the window manually after.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately I already tried that property (forgot to mention in OP). I may also need to add that I'm using DevExpress components; they override Form (XtraForm) - could that be part of the problem (that they are somehow overriding the SuspendDraw / ResizeRedraw / ... properties)?